# Give User Access To Sign A File

Tags: windows, certificate, code-signing, signtool

At the command prompt, as administrator, I can sign a file with signtool.exe. 15063.137. However, I am signing a file from within in app, and when I execute the same command from within the app, the command fails with an exit code of 1. I'm not 100% sure it's a permissions problem, but I'm guessing that it is. How can I give permission to the user that the app is running under to sign a file.

Do, I need to give the user special permission to use the certificate I am using?

PS: I've tried importing the certificate in to Trusted Publishers for the computer account, but for some reason, the certificate doesn't show up there in mmc.

Answer (score 0):

I run signtool with just a normal-rights command box and I do not see a UAC prompt.

But this is with the certificate exported as a pfx file, for example:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit\SignTool.exe" sign /f c:\folder\cert.pfx /p PASSWORD /as /fd sha256 /tr http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp  /v "c:\folder\sub folder\file.exe"
```

Comment: What is a UAC prompt?

Comment: I can do the same. I can run the command at the prompt without an issue. The problem is when an app tries to call signtool. I think that the app's user doesn't have permission somehow.

Comment: UAC = User Access Control.  Applications set to Run As Administrator show a UAC prompt at startup for you to allow it to have those rights.  If you are using a non-admin account then you also must supply an admin password.  SignTool does not require admin rights to run.  Access rights errors would be from lacking read access to the PFX or write access to the EXE.

Comment: ... or the EXE's folder.   Signing a file in Program Files would require admin rights.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I've checked the files (the certificate, and the target file for signing), and I can confirm that the IIS user has read/write access to these files.

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is not a permissions problem... I have checked that the user account for the w3wp process is SYSTEM. I checked all 3 files (certificate, signtool.exe, and target file). SYSTEM has full access for all three files.

Comment: If that 1 is from GetLastError that is ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION not ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  Perhaps you have a bug in the process execution code for example by not placing quotes where needed.

Comment: While that is a slight possibility, I sincerely doubt it... The code has been running fine up until now. I've signed many files like this. The only thing that has changed is the certificate. Later, I changed the signtool version - but that was only after I started getting the error in the first place.